# How to reference a WTForms Form Field in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, wtforms, form-fields

I'm using WTForms to create a form with fields that have "sub fields" like so -

```
class TableName(FlaskForm):
   schema = StringField('Schema', validators=[DataRequired()], id = 'schema_name')
   table = StringField('Table', validators=[DataRequired()], id = 'table_name')

class QaForm(FlaskForm):
   test_table_in = FormField(TableName, id = 'test_table')
   prod_table_in = FormField(TableName, id = 'prod_table')
```

Front end looks like this -
[fields consisting of "sub-fields"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmYcN.png)

How do I reference this form element in JQuery? I've tried the below but it gives me an "undefined" error when I try to print the variables -

```
var tables = {
                test_table: $('#test_table-schema_name').val() + "." + $('#test_table-table_name').val(),
                prod_table: $('#prod_table-schema_name').val() + "." + $('#prod_table-table_name').val()
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out yet? Have you tried using your browser inspect element tool to view the variable name of the field you're seeking?

Comment: Yes, it turns out this the issue was unrelated to how I was calling the form elements.